# Ubuntu 18.04 mt7601u Disk Writing Problems

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I have newly installed 18.04 on a Dell Optiplex. The desktop is connected to the internet using a wired network and does not have any wifi adapters or dongles attached. I am having problems with continous writing to disk and freezing. Looking at the sysylog seems to be showing lots of problems related to mt7601u which, I understand is a wifi adapter and so is not needed.

This is the result of iwconfig:

```
eno1      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I have run rfkill list all and sudo modprobe mt7601u && dmesg | grep mt76. The results are as follows:

```
[  896.316705] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[  896.476736] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[  896.476776] mt7601u: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -110
[  897.183572] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[  897.184230] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[  897.591629] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: EEPROM ver:0c fae:00
[  897.751272] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751322] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751345] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[  897.751354] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751368] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[  897.751372] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[  897.751376] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[  897.751403] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751483] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751514] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751534] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[  897.751539] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[  897.751553] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751567] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[  897.751570] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[  897.751605] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751622] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp urb failed:-71
[  897.751632] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
[  897.751639] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: MCU resp evt:0 seq:5-4!
[  897.751642] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: mt7601u_mcu_wait_resp timed out
[  897.908636] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Vendor request req:07 off:0080 failed:-71
[  898.072659] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[  898.236641] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-71
[  898.236687] mt7601u: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -110
```

With these errors recurring throughout the sysylog. Any idea how I can turn mt7601u off or remove it?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have an Anker wireless and mouse attached. Could they be causing the problems?

Comment: Disable Wi-Fi in BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you blacklist the module. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r mt7601u
echo “blacklist mt7601u” >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.